# Fill static pdf with xml source

Tags: xml, pdf, itext, livecycle-designer, xfa

I'm producing dynamic pdf-files that are filled with an xml data source:
The pdf is created in LiveCycle Designer, then I'm using iTextSharp to fill it dynamically:

```
stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(sourceXml);
```

Some mobile devices however have problems opening dynamic pdfs (apple, android), so I'm looking for a way to make my pdf static after filling in the xfa form. If that's not possible programmatically maybe someone knows a way how to do that with Adobe Acrobat.